# MVC: AutoComplete for novice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am trying to create a autocomplete box in my Asp.Net MVC applicaion.
This is what i've done till now
My viewModel

```
public class CreateAppointment
{
    public string SuperOfficeEmail { get; set; }
}
```

In controller I have this methods

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Person(string searchText)
    {
        var persons = FindPersons(searchText);
        return Content(?? don't know what to do)
    }
```

In view I have

```
@model DatePicker.Models.ViewModels.CreateAppointment
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","Appointment"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SuperOfficeEmail)
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#SuperOfficeEmail").
        autocomplete('@Url.Action("Persons", "Appointment")', { minChars: 1 });   
        });

</script>
```

In `ActionResult Person` `var persons` holds `List<AddressBookPersons>`
and AddressBookPersons class looks like this

```
public class AddressBookPerson
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

What I wanted to do was when autocomplete appears show the FirstName+LastName as text and when user selects certain options I get Email as value of the textbox. Like we do in dropdownlist.
Is that possible (may be using Ajax?)? How do i do that? 
I haven't used autocomplete before and was following this site [tutorial](http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/auto-complete-in-razor-mvc-with-jquery-and-linq-to-entities/), also I'm quite new to jquery.

Comment: What you are describing is not really autocomplete, it's more like a search by name function to put an email address in a textbox... That would be counterintuitive to users. Maybe it's better to have a [...] button next to the textbox that users can click to perform a search in a modal dialog. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: yea, I want more like a dropdownlist lets say where u can search the dropdowlist and each time user types something dropdownlist gets filtered with matching text (based upon first name lets say). Strange situation

Comment: Then have a look at the many combobox-like plugins for jQuery. That's really what you need.